# Printing results to text file

Tags: python

I am wanting to print the results shown in my console from the loop below into a text file. I have tried putting this code in the loop as seen in the example:

```
        f = open('out.txt', 'w',)
        sys.stdout = f
```

However when this is in the loop I only get one set of results instead of the full expected.

```
wordlist = input("What is your word list called?")
f = open(wordlist)
l = set(w.strip().lower() for w in f)
chatlog = input("What is your chat log called?")
with open(chatlog) as f:
    found = False
    for line in f:
        line = line.lower()
        if any(w in line for w in l):
            print (l)
            print(line)
            found = True
            f = open('out.txt', 'w',)
            sys.stdout = f
    if not found:
        print("not here")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `write()` function to write your result into the file.

Code should be something as:

```
wordlist = input("What is your word list called?")
f = open(wordlist)
l = set(w.strip().lower() for w in f)
chatlog = input("What is your chat log called?")

with open(chatlog) as f:
    found = False
    file = open("out.txt", "w")
    for line in f:
        line = line.lower()
        if any(w in line for w in l):
            found = True
            file.write(line)
    if not found:
        print("not here")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you open the 'out.txt' for writing outside the loop, not inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write text to a file, you should use the `.write()` method of the `File` object, as specified in https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html, rather than the `print` method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, each iteration you open it with write mode
Due to [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

> 'w' for writing (truncating the file if it already exists)

for your purposes you should use `"a"` mode (append) or open file out of cycle